# getting incompatible shape error in tensorflow functional model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am trying to implement a deep model using tensorflow.keras which contains an embedding layer + Conv1D + 2 BiLstm layers. This is the implementation in sequential mode:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=limit_on_length, trainable=False))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(50, 4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=200, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)))
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=200, return_sequences=False,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)))
model.add(layers.Dense(len(set(tr_intents)), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

And I fit the model like this:

```
model.fit(train_padded, to_categorical(tr_intents), epochs=15, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
```

Everything goes on very good in this sequential mode. But when I implement the model in functional mode, I get this kind of error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 22) and (32, 11, 22) are incompatible
```

And here is my implementation in functional structure:

```
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(None,))
x = layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=limit_on_length, trainable=False)(input_layer)
x = layers.Conv1D(50, 4, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=200, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(x)
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=200, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(x)
intents_out = layers.Dense(n_intents, activation='softmax')(x)
model = models.Model(input_layer, intents_out)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

Can anybody help me with this error? I need to implement the model in functional mode cause I have to add one more output layer to it.
Number of my intents(or labels) is 22 and each sentence has length of 11.

Comment: Set `return_sequences = False` in Functional.

Comment: @Frightera It worked, but now I have to add a crf layer on top of the last bilstm in parallel with the dense output layer and I have to set the return sequence equal to true. Do you have any idea that how can I handle this?